# how to use a different <link> tag in the head tag depending on what IOS device is being used?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, tags

I am working on making a web app for IOS devices, one of the link tags I am useing in the head tag is:

`<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/startup.png" />`

what this does is create a splash screen image that desplays for a second before the app opens. but with this image, it must be a specific size to work. which is different for Iphone/Ipod and Ipad.

my question is how can I use a different image (with the Ipad's image size requirement), that is only used when an Ipad user is useing the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `<link>` tags each with their own `media` attribute, which will determine whether or not they are loaded based on a media query. For example:

```
<!-- iPhone 3.5" Non-Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px)" href="images/startup-320x460.png">
<!-- iPhone 3.5" Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/startup-640x920.png">
<!-- iPhone 4" Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/startup-640x1096.png">

<!-- iPad Non-Retina Portrait -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="images/startup-768x1004.png">
<!-- iPad Non-Retina Landscape -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="images/startup-748x1024.png">
<!-- iPad Retina Portrait -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/startup-1536x2008.png">
<!-- iPad Retina Landscape -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px)  and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/startup-2048x1496.png">
```

Comment: thanks! and just checking, does this cover all idevice's screens?

Comment: Yes, that should handle every iOS device currently produced.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery and then check against the function.

After the check you can reference against this and update the `<link>` reference based on what the JQuery check returns.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

**OR**

Another method but not as efficient in my opinion is direct reference with `CSS`. You could use this to alter the image size according to the size of the screen.

```
/* Smartphones ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #some-element { display: none; }
}
```